If $A>0$ and $B$ diagonalizable with positive eigenvalues, then $tr(AB)>0$.
$A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $A>0$ (symmetric positive definite) and $B$ diagonalizable with positive eigenvalues. Is it true that $tr(AB)>0$? It seems true to me, but I don't know how to prove it. If we assume $B$ diagonal, then it's easy. Another thing that I've tried was to show $Re(\lambda)$ is positive for $\lambda \in spec(AB)$, but I just couldn't and anyway, that would be an even stronger result. Any indication would be highly appreciated.

Take $B$ with negative $(1,1)$ element. Now take $A$ diagonal with huge $(1,1)$ element and every other diagonal element very close to zero. It should give you a counterexample already for 2x2 matrices

$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 6 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$
has eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ so it is diagonalizable.
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 10 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
is symmetric and positive definite. $Tr(AB)=-6$
